# SQL Alias - Limited to just a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, alias

I've looked around and it seems like it is not possible but the question is, when using an Alias for a column name, am i limited to just a string alias?

I have a stored procedure that dumps some data into a temp table which i query later to export a report.

There are a few columns on this temp table that represent data from specific weeks and it would be helpful to have the date of the week as the column name, but i can't seem to be able to do that using the date variable used in the stored procedure (@dt).

I can do this manipulation of the column names in the application and achieve the same result, but it would be cleaner if i could keep this type of logic in the stored procedure instead of spreading it between the DB and the application.

Example:

```
declare @myname varchar(10)
set @myname = 'My Name'
SELECT FirstName AS '@myname'
FROM User
WHERE LastName = 'Smith'
```

Thanks

Comment: What prevents you from converting the date to a string in your stored procedure?

Comment: "@dt" **is** a string. Are you asking whether you can make the alias **dynamic**?

Comment: Nothing, my question is how do i use a variable as the alias name. For example, i have a variable as such: set @ name = 'myname'. Then a statement as such: SELECT FirstName AS @ name FROM Names. Can that be done?

Comment: Dynamic in the sense that the column name will take its value from whatever the value in the variable is (a string value, for example) when the procedure runs, like the example above.

Comment: You can only do this with dynamic sql.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [How to set a column alias as the result of a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954284/how-to-set-a-column-alias-as-the-result-of-a-sql-query/37954494)

Answer (score 0):

Put your alias name in double quotes like this:

```
 select categoryid "@2" from Category
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on SQL Server 2008. It doesn't like the double quotes, and if i try with single quotes it just treats the whole thing as a string and doesn't give the actual value of the variable.

Comment: @TSiqueira: I think you need to turn on ansi quotes in SQL Server to make it behave like a normal DBMS.