# How to set a column alias as the result of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, alias

I need to use result of a SQL query to set column aliases. Please see below script and the result of the script I need to use it as column aliases.

```
select 
   convert(varchar,DATEADD(month, -12, dateadd(d,-day(convert(date,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()))),convert(date,dateadd(d,+1-(day(getdate())),getdate())))),107),
   convert(varchar,convert(date,dateadd(d,-day(convert(date,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()))),convert(date,dateadd(d,+1-(day(getdate())),getdate())))),107)
```

I need the answer for my question as soon as possible.

Comment: column header of **what**?. Also, we are not a "give me my answer now" kind of service. Actually, we all volunteer here, so it's really rude to come here and ask for an answer "as soon as possible"

Comment: **What** is a column header?

Comment: @JNevill I'm guessing "column alias"

Comment: If you don't know the column headers in advance, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` for this -- first get the values and then use them as the column names.

Comment: Lamak- I am really sorry for my words... it was never my intention. What i need is cell value in a resultset as column alias.

Comment: Yes the cell value is dynamic and i dont know how to get it dynamically.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions are described in the following link: [Column alias based on variable](http://pratchev.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/column-alias-based-on-variable.html)

First solution:

1. Set the alias in a variable
2. Define the query as a nvarchar containing a reference to the variable.
3. Execute the query using sp_executesql

   ```
   SET @column_alias = 'new_title'
   SET @sql = 'SELECT keycol, datacol AS ' + @column_alias + ' FROM Foo'

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql
   ```

Second solution: Rename the column after the execution of the query

```
    INSERT INTO Results
    SELECT keycol, datacol
    FROM Foo

    EXEC sp_rename 'Results.datacol', @column_alias, 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Thanks Alot @Gilles.. It helped a lot!